# How can we run browser in background and Foreground with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver

I am using *Sikuli* and taking some input from user to automate a process. The browser should be in the foreground for sikuli to work properly.

So now, I want the browser to come to the foreground when Sikuli script is working. For that I searched for code on the internet and with this code following code and it is working:

```
driver.manager().maximize();
```

But to take user input from the console of eclipse, how to run browser in background. For that I am not able to find any code on internet.

Please suggest me some method with which selenium script can run browser on the background. Somebody on internet suggest docker-selenium but I don't want to use it and there is no `minimize` method like there is `maximize`.

Comment: This answer sounds like it might solve your problem: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-to-minimize-the-browser-window-which-was-launched-via-selenium-webdriver

Comment: ok, thanks for answer. It will work.